# Blue Prism: is it possible to set a timer on Spys?

Tags: blueprism, spy

I often see that the spy will search for a very long period of time. If it have been looking for a field for more than 15 sec. I would like to have a timer that stops the search. I did not find any solution on the internet or in the setting menu, So is this possible.

Comment: This is not supported - certain types of applications' interface models are notoriously slow to query. Blue Prism will traverse the model at least once, no matter how slow it moves. If this was supported, it'd be a UX nightmare for developers debugging their Application Modelers whose elements are in fact present but a timeout was encountered traversing the application model before the element was encountered within it.

Comment: absolutely agree, can't imagine the frustration of going through some ancestor model tree trying to debug somethign as miniscule as this. @Aske as bad as waitign is you need to curtail your application modeller with some experimentation to figure out what the best fastest combo of attributes are for your app.